# Tornado custom logging

Tags: tornado

I am trying to create my own custom logging handler in Tornado but seem to be hitting a brick wall. I've a very basic test script at the moment shown below where I want to simply test the concept. My code is:

```
 # bunch of imports here

 # logging definitions
 import logging
 myFormat = ("[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s")
 formatter = logging.Formatter(myFormat)
 myLogger = logging.getLogger()
 myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

 class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
         handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
         (r"/process", ProcessHandler),
    ]
    super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, default_handler_class=my404Handler

class ProcessHandler(myBaseHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def _initialize(self):
            res = yield self.buildJSON('I am just testing JSON')
            raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
            self.write("Processing....")
            response = yield self._initialize()
            self.clear()
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
            self.finish(response)


    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def buildJSON(self, xmlText):
            myLogger.debug("Step 1 logging")
            # If you want JSON format, use the code below of 4 lines
            data = {}
            data['MessageOutput'] = xmlText
            data['Format'] = 'json'
            return json.dumps(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fh = logging.FileHandler('xmljson.log')
    fh.setFormatter(myFormat)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # add the handler to logger
    myLogger.addHandler(fh)
    main()
```

The output I get in xmljson.log is below:

```
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
[%(process)d] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s
```

I am missing the 1 error I request "step 1 logging". Nothing shows on the Tornado screen/display which is fine I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your call to `setFormatter`: you need to pass the `Formatter` object instead of just the format string. Change `setFormatter(myFormat)` to `setFormatter(formatter)` and it works.

Comment: Ah!! I made the change, but I still don't see the "step 1 logging" line in the log file. Instead I see:[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:32,160 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.55ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:32,971 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.40ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:33,568 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.39ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:34,027 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.39ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:34,218 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.41ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:34,387 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.40ms
[13545] INFO 2015-10-02 11:07:34,553 304 GET /iq (10.100.1.35) 0.40ms